# Passing a Value from a URL Parameter to Header:Location redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header, http-status-code-301

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

1.) opening http://example.org/go.php?url=http://www.example.com

2.) should 301 redirect to: http://www.example.com

**(TESTING) So far, in out.php this works:**

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
?>
```

**So I went ahead and put this code in go.php:**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
    header("Location: " . $_GET['url']);
    exit();
} else {
    # print the whole $_GET arrays
    # just for debug !
    print_r($_GET);
    die("This field is empty.");
}
?>
```

**It won't work, here is what i get:**

```
A redirect to http://example.org/
```

**http://example.org output:**

[image: just folder contents]

**http://example.org/go.php output:**

[image: without values or parameters]

**http://example.org/go.php?url=http://www.example.com output:**

[image: the whole url redirects back here]

**HINT:** The folder does not contain any other files

Comment: And _how_ does it not work? Sends an error message, simply does nothing, ...?

Comment: the output is updated in the question, please have a look, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's *really* something in the `$_GET` array(). It is also a good practice to have an `exit();` call after your header redirect.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
    header("Location: " . $_GET['url']);
    exit();
} else {
    # print the whole $_GET arrays
    # just for debug !
    print_r($_GET);
    die("This field is empty.");
}
?>
```

Besides the code, try to make clearer what exactly does not work (e.g. you get an error message, etc.) - we do not have a crystal ball...

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look (i also tried your method, but the result is the same) there is also no debug file or print on the screen, if I open the file out.php itself, this is what i get: `Array ( ) This field is empty.` and like I explained in the output when i add the value to the parameter, it redirects

Comment: @user1679901. Weird: getting `Array (  ) ` means that your `url` query param is empty (or absent), while if you really used all of the @Jan's solution (i.e. beginning with `if (!empty($_GET['url']))`) it can't happen! I suggest replacing `print_r($_GET);` by `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`.

Comment: @user1679901: Please post your complete `out.php` code.

Comment: @cFreed also tried `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` but also redirects back to http://example.org/ it returns the message on screen `This field is empty.` when i just open the go.php file itself

Comment: @mikulabc. What I meant when I suggested replacing `print_r($_GET);` by `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` was not a solution to make the code work as you expect, but to look at the echoed query string, to control which information is transmitted. So what did it print before `This field is empty.`?

Comment: @cFreed it did not print anything, because it just redirected back to the main domain, by opening http://example.org/go.php?url=http://www.example.com it just goes back to http://example.org/ (i do know what you meant) is there another way?

Comment: @Jan like i told cfreed, there is no output because it just redirects back, the example of output i gave is when i just open the php file itself, then it displays the simple message  "this field is empty" but i do want to mention one thing, when i enter the url like so http://example.org/go.php?url=www.google.com , it redirects to http://example.org/www.google.com and obviously shows a 404, but it tries to redirect, that is for sure, but not correctly somehow

Comment: @mikulabc It can't happen this way! If you exactly wrote what Jan proposed, then before to display "This field is empty" it _must_ have  first executed the `print_r()`(or the `echo` I suggested in place).

Comment: @cFreed i do want to mention one thing, when i enter the url like so http://example.org/go.php?url=www.google.com , it redirects to http://example.org/www.google.com and obviously shows a 404, but it tries to redirect, that is for sure, but not correctly somehow

Comment: @mikulabc Again, this can't happen (at least with the code you exposed): example.org/go.php?url=www.google.com should redirect to www.google.com, not to example.org/www.google.com!

Comment: @cFreed maybe because i use nginx in combination with apache :/ hmm, anyhow, i finally decided to move on and use a url shortening service on my server, installed it and works perfect, thanks for the effort though